# allow_push on .hg/hgrc doesn't seem to work

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I'm setting up a mercurial server with LDAP auth where I want to allow access per repo so I'm creating a hgrc under .hg for each repo.

```
[web]
allow_push = user1
```

My problem is that If I use these hgrc files I cannot push with any user (abort: authorization failed). If I just use hgweb.config I can do it with no problem

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put those lines in your `hgweb.config` file can you push with *any* user or only the ones you list?  My guess would be that your LDAP is providing user names formatted differently than you expect (perhaps as email addresses, etc.) and so they're not matching.

Check your apache error logs for anything interesting, and consider changing the log format to log the `$REMOTE_USER` environment user to see what's being matched.  Also, make sure your `push_ssl` value is set to false if you're not using SSL connections (though you should).

Comment: if I use hgweb.config I can push only with the correct usernames. if I write any allow_push on the hgrc file I cannot do any push...

Comment: How about logging $REMOTE_USER?  I think it's `%u`.  What is `push_ssl` set to?  Are you using SSL?

Answer (score 1):

When your HTTP server is Nginx, Modify `log_format` to find out which user redirect from Nginx to HG

```
vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                 '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

And see the Nginx log file

```
cat /var/log/nginx/nginx.log
```